# Android Home Screen Widget Failing with EditText

Tags: android

Whenever I add an `EditText` widget to the layout of my home screen widget (confusing how the term `widget` is being used twice in the Android lexicon :-/ ), I receive the "Problem Loading Widget" error box.

Here is the layout I'm attempting; if you remove the `EditText,` it works...

```
<RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

             <Button
                     android:id="@+id/button_generate"
                     android:layout_width="54px"
                     android:layout_height="54px"
                     android:text="Generate"
                     android:textSize="10sp"
                     android:gravity="center"
                     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edittext_key">
             </Button>   

             <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/textview_hash"
                     android:layout_width="75px"
                     android:layout_height="45px"
                     android:text="Password"
                     android:textSize="11sp"
                     android:gravity="left"
                     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/edittext_key">
             </TextView>

             <EditText
                     android:id="@+id/edittext_data2"
                     android:layout_width="200px"
                     android:layout_height="50px"
                     android:textSize="12sp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="20px"
                     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
             </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, the Google Search home screen widget has an `EditText,` so it's obviously legal to implement.  Any thoughts on why this is not working?

Comment: "the Google Search home screen widget has an EditText" No, it doesn't -- when you click on it, it pops up an EditText. Moreover, AFAIK, that's not an app widget, but rather a feature of the home screen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Widgets use RemoteViews, which only support a certain number of UI elements. EditText is not included. The Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout) shows which are supported.

The Google Search home screen widget actually uses a TextView. ([Source code](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Launcher.git;a=blob;f=res/layout/widget_search.xml;h=f8c59fe314c18cf8a3213f144c8ca35cdfbb77c6;hb=HEAD))