# editable textview in android widget

Tags: android, input, widget, textview, homescreen

Hi I am a novice in android programming. I am trying to create the home screen widget with input textbox. I searched around and I have found so far that EditText is not available for home screen. I also found that TextView is possible to make it editable, but I still have no idea how it works. So, I would like to make TextView editable. How I can do that?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have a look at this [Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915865/android-home-screen-widget-failing-with-edittext/2915935#2915935)

Comment: Check this answer he explained bit more details with text view https://stackoverflow.com/a/30790575

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In My opinion make an activity so When they tap the widget, display an activity that has an `EditText`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Currently, I did the same as you suggested, but maybe the better option is creating a dialog box to popup the input box.