# How to display cursor at the end of text in TextView?

Tags: android

I wanted to display blinking cursor at the end of the text in TextView .

I tried by  `android:cursorVisible="true"` in TextView But no go .

Even i tried `text.setCursorVisible(true);` Doesn't work .

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"  />
```

Does any one know any solution for it ?

Comment: You can not.. TextView is not made for take input from user...

Comment: you should be using EditText. That displays the cursor.

Comment: You guys dont know what you talking about. Any view can be overriden to accept input.

Answer (score 6):

First of all you should use `EditText` in place of `TextView` for taking input. If still the cursor doesn't blink, set the  `android:cursorVisible="true"`attribute in `xml file`, it should make the cursor blink. If your cursor is not visible in edit text, that's also a reason one can't see the cursor blinking. Set `android:textCursorDrawable="@null"`. This should solve your problem

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/editext1"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
   android:cursorVisible="true">

</EditText>
```

In your activity class, add this code as well.

```
EditText input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
input.setSelection(input.getText().length());
```

Comment: Interesting downvote. Will the downvoter care for telling the reason of downvoting?

Comment: Does your answer puts cursor at the end?

Comment: try it out works for me. If you downvoted this answer, almost the same answers are given by other people as well. Downvote their answers as well.

Comment: I wanted it for TextView bro..not for EditText.

Comment: you can't do that for textView. If you want to make textView editable, why not use EditText instead

Comment: Text view is for viewing text. Wanting to use text view to edit text is like wanting to drink soup off a plate. On a side note, this works for me but is there an easy way to get the cursor to show up only when editing the text. Mine shows up even when I'm not editing it.

Answer (score 2):

**There is a solution for this.**

I had to do this when I was making a terminal app and I used a simple `runnable` put a cursor at the end and make it blink.

I made 3 class variables:

```
private boolean displayCursor;
private boolean cursorOn;
private String terminalText;

private TextView terminal; // The TextView Object
```

`terminalText` keeps track of the text to be displayed.

Created a class method that runs the `runnable` the first time

```
private void runCursorThread() {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (displayCursor) {
                if (cursorOn) {
                    terminal.setText(terminalText);
                } else {
                    terminal.setText(terminalText + '_');
                }
                cursorOn = !cursorOn;
            }
            terminal.postDelayed(this, 400);
        }
    };
    runnable.run();
}
```

And initiated the variables and called `runCursorThread()` in `onCreate()`

```
    cursorOn = false;
    displayCursor = true;
    runCursorThread();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should go for `EditText`. You can set its background and make it appears like `TextView` with below code.

#### Step 1

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >
</EditText>
```

#### Step 2

```
EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtText);
edt.setSelection(edt.getText().length());
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: do you think you suggested answer puts cursor at the end?

Comment: What he wants is `at the end of the text in TextView`. So end of text means not right side my dear dear friend. If I m not wrong. You should be careful before downvote. You should try code before that.

Comment: I want to display blinking cursor at the end of text in TextView , not in TextEditor man.

Comment: @Uday, What I suggested will look like text view. Wait I am posting image so that you can understand it quickly.

Comment: i will vote you up , because you gave the alternative way chrees.

Comment: @mohit, hi mohit. I edited my answer. Please check that. It has also image so that you don't need to implement :)

Comment: Good, But you guys just changed his mind it wasn't the sol and even there was no solution for what he asked originally. Reason for down voting was that if guys like you (guess you are wiki member) would start answering like this then this site would lose its charm. I could also answer this but i didn't cos its better to say no than giving a false sol.

Comment: even i agree with @mohit . I will try to find the solution for it hope it will be help full for others. 
Cheers to u all guys ..:)

Comment: @mohit, Vote up your comment ...Totally agree with you mohit. But what I found is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056054/android-how-to-make-textview-editable, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481111/editable-textview-in-android-widget, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/4kK94mzRaRc.. After reading those article and forum, you can say me your opinion and I will delete my answer. :)

Comment: I m still there as 2 of them are novice programmers in android and they don't even know the nuts and bolts of Android like you do..So eventually it becomes the duty of seniors to put their fellow juniors into right directions instead of giving them their first lesson as a hack solution.

Comment: You are a nice guy. Don't delete, let it be. It was pleasure talking to you :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally Fixed this Using the EditText as per **@Chintan Rathod** advice.

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/text"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"/> //reference to @Chintan Rathod.
```

**Code**

```
EditText text=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("hello");
text.setSelection(text.getText().length()); // reference to @Umer Farooq code.
```