# How to make a TextView editable at the click of a button?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, view, android-xml

I have an app that displays certain content from a database and lets users edit it. I have an activity that displays those details in some textviews. Now, there is an "EDIT" button at the bottom of the screen. When this button is clicked, I want to make the textview's editable (which are initially read-only) so that the database can be updated. Also, I want the "EDIT" button to turn into a "SAVE" button. I understand I can just use another activity for this, but is there any way to do this while in the same activity?

Comment: did the answer solve your requirement?

Comment: Simply set the focus to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How to make TextView editable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056054/android-how-to-make-textview-editable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`EditText` is a `TextView`, what it can do `TextView` can do better

so suppose you have a `TextView`

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:text="i am a text"
    android:textColor="#243b03" />
```

and you want it to be editable by a click of a button; in your onclick add this

```
   TextView.setCursorVisible(true);
   TextView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
   TextView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
   TextView.requestFocus(); //to trigger the soft input
```

they are not static, but i made it static so you know which view object's methods are those. About your Button after the text has been inputted then you change the text to "done" or whatever, `Button` extends from `TextView` so treat it as if it was-research on `TextWatcher`

Comment: I have a textview named description' and there's no such method named `description.setEdittable(Boolean)`. It says "cannot resolve method 'setEdittable(boolean)' "

Comment: sorry sir take that out, that is use in xml and also its deprecated.. sorry.@SumodKulkarni

Comment: i can't find keyboard show up upon click. How to make it pop up?

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off to switch the TextView to an EditText and toggle it with `editText.setEnabled(boolean)` to get the effect you want

Comment: `TextView` is editable in nature hence `EditText` is a `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

Making a textview editable has its limitations, such as not being able to modify the data already in it (Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056054/android-how-to-make-textview-editable) answer)

You can just use an EditText and use `android:inputType="none"` in xml or use `<your_editText>.setEnabled(false)` in your activity/fragment to make it read-only.  After the user clicks EDIT, you can make the editText editable by putting  the below statements inside the button's onClick method.

`<your_editText>.setEnabled(true) 
<your_editText>.requestFocus();`

Regarding making the EDIT button turn into SAVE, you can put a counter inside your onClick method which will keep track of the order of clicks. After the first click you can change the button text using

`<your_button>.setText("SAVE")`.

On the next click you can execute whatever statements you're using to save data.